# How to make app default device Assistant for SMS and call log permission?

Tags: google-developers-console

I want to ask for SMS and call log permission from user for which google ask me to make it as default assistant. I've done that but every time they reject my update by saying:

> #### No default handler capability
>
> Default handler capability for Default Assistant handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler) was listed on your declaration form, but your app does not appear to have default handler capability. Please submit a revised Permissions Declaration Form and/or add default handler capability to your app.

How can I fix this problem?